# error pip install scipy on command prompt

Tags: scipy, pip

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\akbar>sudo -i
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
C:\Users\akbar>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\akbar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yr7qne_9\scipy\setup.py", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\akbar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yr7qne_9\scipy\setup.py", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 315, in __init__
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\dist.py", line 428, in fetch_build_egg
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\command\easy_install.py", line 652, in easy_install
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 635, in fetch_distribution
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 616, in find
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 559, in download
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 804, in _download_url
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 810, in _attempt_download
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg\setuptools\package_index.py", line 725, in _download_to
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 449, in read
        n = self.readinto(b)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\http\client.py", line 493, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\socket.py", line 586, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 1002, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 865, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
      File "C:\Users\akbar\Miniconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 625, in read
        v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
```

---

Command `python setup.py egg_info` failed with error code 1 in `C:\Users\akbar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-yr7qne_9\scipy\`

`C:\Users\akbar>sd`

i have no idea what should i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install scipy in Windows from a [binary](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#scipy)
or [any of the scientific python distributions](https://www.scipy.org/install.html#scientific-python-distributions) (recommended).

However, looks like a network error. So try `pip install scipy  --no-cache-dir` to skip install from cache.